# Setting an event for a button

Tags: android

I've asked a question similar to this. The point of this code is to check if a checklist is checked, if it is than it adds 1 to the score.
I've been told that the problem is that I haven't set an event. Please explain what I need to do to make it work, I'm new to android development and have been stuck on this for a few days. Please give a code example with your answer.

```
package xyz.ashraf.whoisdelasalle;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;

/**
 * Created by Ashraf on 3/2/2016.
 */
public class check_Button extends Pop_sallian{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.popwindow_sallian);
        // Connects The variable to an xml id


        TextView output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);

        final int[] score = {0};
        //sets the variable to 0



         OnCheckedChangeListener checkedListener = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                switch(buttonView.getId()){
                    case R.id.concern:
                        score[0]++;
                        break;
                    case R.id.faith:
                        score[0]++;
                        break;
                    case R.id.respect:
                        score[0]++;
                        break;
                    case R.id.education:
                        score[0]++;
                        break;
                    case R.id.community:
                        score[0]++;
                        break;
                }
            }
        };

        // adds the variables together to form a score

        if(score[0] == 0){
            output.setText("Come on! Get involved, your la sallian community needs you.");
        } else if(score[0] == 1){
            output.setText("Good start, keep going!");
        } else if(score[0] == 2){
            output.setText("Room to improve but doing good!");
        } else if(score[0] == 3){
            output.setText("Very good, others look up to you!");
        } else if(score[0] == 4){
            output.setText("Wow, you really are an inspiration");
        } else if(score[0] == 5){
            output.setText("Excellent! You're a leader in your la sallian community. Nice work!");
        } else{
            output.setText("Unknown");
        }
        // changes the output text based on score value
    }
}
```

^^checklist code^^

```
package xyz.ashraf.whoisdelasalle;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.who);
        Button today = (Button) findViewById(R.id.today);
        Button sallian = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sallian);
        Button how = (Button) findViewById(R.id.toBe);
        Button moreInfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.info);

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Pop.class));
            }
        });

        today.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Pop_today.class));
            }
        });
        sallian.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Pop_sallian.class));
            }
        });
        how.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Pop_how.class));
            }
        });
        moreInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Pop_info.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

^^Code where the button is and, when pressed calls on the checklist code, The Ok button is to close the pop up when pressed^^

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    android:elevation="8dp"

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Are you a Sallian?"
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Do you meet the following prerequisites, if you do you may be a Sallian"
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Are you concerened for the poor and Social Justice?"
        android:id="@+id/concern"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Do you have faith in the presence of God?"
        android:id="@+id/faith"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/concern"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Do you have Respect for all people?"
        android:id="@+id/respect"
        android:layout_below="@+id/faith"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Do you value education?"
        android:id="@+id/education"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/respect"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Are you inclusive in your community?"
        android:id="@+id/community"
        android:layout_below="@+id/education"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:checked="false" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ok"
        android:id="@+id/okButton_sallian"
        android:layout_below="@+id/community"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="#FAFAFA"
        android:textColor="#00E676"
        android:elevation="2dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Check"
        android:id="@+id/check"
        android:textColor="#00E676"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:background="#FAFAFA"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/okButton_sallian"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:id="@+id/output"
        android:textColor="#1eff00"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/community"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/check" />
</RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

^^ xml code the code takes for^^

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a checked listener, but doing nothing with it. You need to set it to your checkbox or checkboxes.

```
mCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.concern);
mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangedListener(checkedListener);
```

Just like you do on your buttons.

Comment: I understand what you're saying but how exactly what I implement that? Would I have to get rid of the cases and breaks? Thanks for your help!

Comment: In the activity or fragment where you load the layout that contains the checkbox, you create a CheckedChangedListener, locate the checkbox (findViewById) and assign the listener to the checkbox. You are doing the same with the buttons, it's the same principle.

Comment: So do I do one for each checklist?

Comment: You can have 1 listener per checkbox, or you can have a single listener for all checkboxes and then in the listener you determine which checkbox was clicked with the method view.getId(). Whichever you prefer.